# Install pysftp on EC2 linux instance failure

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pip

I have an AWS EC2 linux instance and I'm trying to install pysftp to write python script to manage files in STFP server.

```
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='/tmp/pip-build-jFfbH5/cryptography/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install 
--record /tmp/pip-gok42x-record/install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed 
--compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-jFfbH5/cryptography/
```

My python version is 2.7 and pip version is 8.1.2. Both pip and sudo pip points to path "/usr/local/bin/pip"

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: I know it has been many years but were you ever able to get this resolved?